# AngularJS legacy integration and content that contains asynchronously changing id doesn't trigger watcher

Tags: javascript, angularjs, legacy-code

I have a legacy page that has a `<input type="hidden" id="myId" value="somenumber">` that is populated with Jquery (legacy code) asynchronously after the page loads for the first time. On this page I am trying to have an angularjs directive. The only problem is I am trying to watch on #myId value so I can use it for my directive but the value changes and triggers the watcher once and it is empty - it doesn't happen again when it actually gets a numercal value from jquery. What am I doing wrong? I tried with ng-value,ng-model but still I get undefined for those attempts. Also it is not possible to introduce routing etc to get the id from there.. Thanks

Here is my directive:

```
angular.module("myModule")
.directive("myDir", function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        templateUrl: "template.html",
        scope : {},
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
            scope.$watch(function () { return $("#myId").val() }, function (newVal) { ctrl.myId= newVal});
        },
        controllerAs: 'myCtrl'
    };

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular is unaware of the jquery change (obviously). You can emit the data in a custom event in jQuery, capture that event in angular and rebroadcast it  to your directive to get it the first time.

Here is a plunkr with it working: http://plnkr.co/edit/RTIzEudC7TktDTSdqWnQ
It will update the binding on the page after jquery emits an event 5 seconds after page load

```
//emit in jquery
$(document).trigger('customEvent', data);

app.run(['$rootScope', function ($rootScope) {
    //capture jQuery events and re-broadcast them as angular events
                //events to capture
                var events = [
                    'customEvent'
                ];

                //To Use: $scope.$on('eventName', function(ngEvent, jqEvent, data)
                $(document).on(events.join(' '), function(e) {
                    $rootScope.$broadcast.apply($rootScope, [e.type].concat(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 0)));
                });
});

//listen for it in directive
scope.$on('customEvent', function(){
    scope.$apply(function(){
        //do stuff here and angular will be aware of it
    });
});
```

Comment: +1 Ok but if I have let's say 20 directives as I will soon - I don't want each of them to be notified for distinct id changes.. Is there a better way?

Comment: Not that I can think of. Generally you want to go all in with Angular so its not really built to function like this. Someone else might have a better solution, but this is how I handle random jQuery events that can't be moved to angular in projects.

Comment: the interesting part is if I do press a button and then have a function that just gets  the id based on the $("myId") it works fine. It would be nice if watcher function was called many times till it has a value

Comment: Yea, watchers are awesome until something happens that they are unaware of. Then the fix is never as easy as you'd like!

Comment: I tried it and it worked.. do you have an idea why I cannot  see it in {{ myCtrl.myId}} in the template of the directive?

Comment: it appears that whatever I do in the scope.$on() is not reflected in the templates...

Comment: You need to apply the changes, I'll update the example

Comment: I tried applying but it said it was already in a $digest cycle - I will try your change